# On iPhone Bootsrap Popover not closing when click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, popover

When i click outside the popover is not closing on iPhone.

Here is the code:

```
 $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
            // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
        });
    });
```

Any solution?